# Counting the number of occurences - loop invariant

Tags: correctness-proof, hoare-logic, loop-invariants

I'm trying to come up with loop invariant for the following program.

```
k = a[0]
m = 1
p = 1
while p < n:
    if a[p] == k:
        m += 1
    p += 1
return m
```

I belive this program returns the number equal to the number of occurences of element a[0] in my array "a".

I thought maybe this is a good cadidate:

|{i: 0 <= i <= n and a[0] == a[i]}| = m

Am I ok? If not, is this even the right direction to go?

Comment: $i\leq n$ should probably be $i<p$ instead, otherwise the invariant is false when the loop starts.

Comment: Try proving it correct!